# getMapAsync() not functioning

Tags: android, google-maps, nullpointerexception

I am getting an error to use a callback when using `getMapAsync()` since `getMap()` is deprecated. Any ideas on how to update this code so that error doesn't get thrown? Pulling in an `API` to locate pins on a map

`05-26 22:50:13.419 12576-12576/com.example.kdotz.zoo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.kdotz.zoo, PID: 12576 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.animateCamera(com.goog‌​le.android.gms.maps.‌​CameraUpdate, com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$CancelableCallback)' on a null object reference`

---

```
public class ZooMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

public static ZooMapFragment getInstance(){
    ZooMapFragment fragment = new ZooMapFragment();

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    CameraPosition position = CameraPosition.builder()
            .target(new LatLng(39.7494, -104.9498))
            .zoom(16f)
            .bearing(0.0f)
            .tilt(0.0f)
            .build();

    getMapAsync().animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition( position ), null);
    getMapAsync().setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    getMapAsync().setTrafficEnabled( true );

    getMapAsync().getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled( true );

    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().position( new LatLng( 39.7500, -104.9500 ) );
    options.title( "Zoo" );
    options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker( BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE ) );
    getMapAsync().addMarker( options );

    getMapAsync().setOnMarkerClickListener( new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            marker.showInfoWindow();
            return true;
        }
    });

    RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(getString(R.string.pins_feed))
            .build();

    PinsApiInterface pinsApiInterface = adapter.create(PinsApiInterface.class);

    pinsApiInterface.getStreams(new Callback<List<Pin>>() {
        @Override
        public void success(List<Pin> pins, Response response) {
            for(Pin pin: pins){
                Log.e("Zoo", pin.getName());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

        }
    });
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    // Add a marker in Denver, Zoo
    // and move the map's camera to the same location.
    LatLng denverZoo = new LatLng(39.7500, -104.9500);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(denverZoo)
            .title("Marker in Denver Zoo"));
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(denverZoo));

}
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Please post the logcat output

Comment: `05-26 22:50:13.419 12576-12576/com.example.kdotz.zoo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.example.kdotz.zoo, PID: 12576
                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.animateCamera(com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate, com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$CancelableCallback)' on a null object reference`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only call `getMapAsync()` once, and when the map is ready, the `onMapReady()` callback will give you the GoogleMap reference.  Then you can manipulate the GoogleMap as needed.

Also note that since the ZooMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment, there is no need to use `onViewCreated()`, you can just use the `onResume()` override.

```
public class ZooMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment 
        implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    public ZooMapFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        setUpMapIfNeeded();

        //Other stuff:
        RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
          .setEndpoint(getString(R.string.pins_feed))
          .build();

        PinsApiInterface pinsApiInterface = adapter.create(PinsApiInterface.class);

        pinsApiInterface.getStreams(new Callback<List<Pin>>() {
            @Override
            public void success(List<Pin> pins, Response response) {
                for(Pin pin: pins){
                    Log.e("Zoo", pin.getName());
                }
            }
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            getMapAsync(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);


        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener( new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
          @Override
          public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            marker.showInfoWindow();
            return true;
          }
        });

         // Add a marker in Denver, Zoo
        // and move the map's camera to the same location.
        LatLng denverZoo = new LatLng(39.7500, -104.9500);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(denverZoo)
                .title("Marker in Denver Zoo"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(denverZoo, 15));
    }
}
```